# What is the fastest way to find the length of an object member in an element in a collection?

Tags: python

Suppose, I have a list of objects.

Each object has, among others, three properties: `kind: str`, `name: str`, and `brief_description: str`. I need to find the length of the longest `name` and longest `brief_description`. I also need to segregate elements into separate dictionaries according to their `kind`.

I am doing the following:

```
def __calculate_max(self, member_def_list):
    key_index = 0
    for mem in member_def_list:
        kind = mem.kind
        if "variable" == kind:
            var_key = mem.get_file_name_to_write_on()  # obtain id and use it as a key
            if Utils.key_exists(self.__attr_dictionary, var_key):
                var_key += str(key_index)
                key_index += 1
            self.__attr_dictionary[var_key] = mem
            var_lll = len(str(mem.name))
            if self.__max_length_of_variable_name < var_lll:
                self.__max_length_of_variable_name = var_lll
            if self.__max_length_of_variable_desc < len(str(mem.get_brief_description())):
                self.__max_length_of_variable_desc = len(str(mem.get_brief_description()))
        elif "function" == kind:
            f_key = mem.get_file_name_to_write_on()  # obtain id and use it as a key
            if Utils.key_exists(self.__function_dictionary, f_key):
                f_key += str(key_index)
                key_index += 1
            self.__function_dictionary[f_key] = mem
            f_lll = len(str(mem.get_name_and_args_string()))
            if self.__max_length_of_function_name < f_lll:
                self.__max_length_of_function_name = f_lll
            if self.__max_length_of_function_desc < len(str(mem.get_brief_description())):
                self.__max_length_of_function_desc = len(str(mem.get_brief_description()))
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Better means more lightweight and faster.

Comment: A dictionnary where the keys are names + index, the dict structure may be `key:str , value:list`

Comment: I would be curious to see your `Utils.key_exists` because the code to do is just `if var_key in self.__attr_dictionary`

Comment: @azro, yes, you are correct. That is what inside.

Comment: Does `get_brief_description` only do `return self.brief_description` ?

Comment: @azro, Yes..... `brief_descripion` is an object, rather than a string.

Comment: As an aside, you really probably shouldn't be using double-underscore name-mangling. Python != Java, double-underscore name-mangling does not mean "private".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can simplify max computation, using `max` method, that reduces 3 lines into 1 (for the 4 times you use it)
- use `collections.defaultdict` to get data structure like this `Dict[str, List[str]]`, so you don't have to bother with a `key_index` to append to the key in case of duplication

```
# from collections import defaultdict
def __init__(self):
    self.__attr_dictionary = defaultdict(list)
    self.__function_dictionary = defaultdict(list)

def __calculate_max(self, member_def_list: list[Member]):
    for mem in member_def_list:
        if mem.kind == "variable":
            var_key = mem.get_file_name_to_write_on()
            self.__attr_dictionary[var_key].append(mem)

            self.__max_length_of_variable_name = max(self.__max_length_of_variable_name,
                                                     len(str(mem.name)))
            self.__max_length_of_variable_desc = max(self.__max_length_of_variable_desc,
                                                     len(str(mem.get_brief_description())))

        elif mem.kind == "function":
            f_key = mem.get_file_name_to_write_on()
            self.__function_dictionary[f_key].append(mem)

            self.__max_length_of_function_name = max(self.__max_length_of_function_name,
                                                     len(str(mem.get_name_and_args_string())))
            self.__max_length_of_function_desc = max(self.__max_length_of_function_desc,
                                                     len(str(mem.get_brief_description())))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use python lambda functionality to reduce coding such sorting process.

```
ls = [{"name": "evanescence", "brief_description": " an American rock band founded"},
  {"name": "Metallica", "brief_description": "an American heavy metal band"}]

ls = sorted(ls, key=lambda x: len(x["name"]))
```

after choosing your key or policy for sorting, you can sort such a list and after that, you can filter your list to get your result.
The result of the above code is ...

```
[{'name': 'Metallica', 'brief_description': 'an American heavy metal band'}, {'name': 'evanescence', 'brief_description': ' an American rock band founded'}]
```

Comment: There is no such thing about sorting in the code, that is about `max`